# D-link router admin password reset

Tags: wireless-router, password-recovery

I forget my D-link admin password. I search but haven't found a proper solution. How can I reset to a new password. My D-link router model is DIR-600L.

Comment: You should really google search your title..

Answer (score 2):

Hold the reset button for 30 seconds is the standard way to reset any router to factory default.

Then use the factory default user name and password to relogin to the default ip address of the router to enter the router's configuration interface.

Answer (score 2):

For most D-link routers you can power on the router, find the "reset" button (it will be recessed on the bottom or back) so get something link a paperclip and hold it down for 10 seconds approx. until the router's lights blink. The default admin name & pass should now be restored.

Comment: 10 seconds is usually not enough time, the lowest i've seen is 15 seconds, i tell people 30 seconds to be on the safe side.

Comment: Agreed Sickest, I can confirm this for some routers.